# Query on a table to get 2 counts in a single query.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL

> **table1**(Date(full_date), app_id, type(free, paid))
>   **table2**(Date_fk, Year, month, day, quater)

**Query for Single Count is :**

```
select Year, count(*) 
from Table1, Table2 
where Table1.Date = Table2.Date  and Table1.Type='Free' 
GROUP BY YEAR 

---------------------
| year | free_count |
---------------------
| 2019 |   10       |
---------------------
```

I want output as

```
---------------------------------
| year | free_count | Paid_count |
----------------------------------
| 2019 |   10       |    12      |
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select year, 
     count(case when t1.type='free' then 1 end) as freecount,
     count(case when t1.type='paid' then 1 end) as paidcount
from table1 t1 
    join table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date  
group by year
```

Also please take a look at the `join` syntax.  In general, I'd highly recommend not using commas in your `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
SELECT
  d.year,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'Free' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS free_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'Paid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS paid_count
FROM Table2 d -- Dates table
LEFT JOIN Table1 a -- Apps table
  ON d.Date_fk = a.Date
GROUP BY d.year;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` guarantees that you'll still get results for those years without any apps.